# iPad app running in simulator using more than 100% of CPU?

Tags: xcode

I am running my app inside the simulator and when I initially run it and debug it etc there is no problem.

The concern comes when I leave it running in the simulator then I open the activity monitor and notice that the app is using about 104% of the CPU

Anyone have any ideas?

EDIT:  This causes the fan to run FULL blast all the time until I quit my app.

> Hardware Overview:
>
> Model Name: MacBook Pro   Model
>   Identifier:   MacBookPro6,2   Processor
>   Name: Intel Core i7   Processor
>   Speed:    2.66 GHz   Number Of
>   Processors:   1   Total Number Of
>   Cores:    2   L2 Cache (per core):    256 KB
>   L3 Cache: 4 MB   Memory:  8 GB
>   Processor Interconnect Speed: 4.8 GT/s
>   Boot ROM Version: MBP61.0057.B0C   SMC
>   Version (system): 1.58f16   Serial
>   Motion Sensor:   State:   Enabled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's because your CPU is dual-core(probably quad-core or more). Which means full use of one core is 100%, and full use of both cores is 200%, etc. This happens in other applications as well.

Comment: But the fan is running on full blast during this!?!?

Comment: 104% for i7 is a lot of calculations. CPU should be very hot. My simulator doesn't take up so much CPU. Try relaunching it, open up a blank app and see how it goes.

Comment: @TheLearner - Have your profiled your application using Instruments when it's within the Simulator?  My guess is that you have a tight loop or some other performance issue within your application that's simply using all available CPU resources.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. The backboardd  process was using > 80% CPU.

I had deleted an app in the iOS simulator and had left all the icons 'jiggling'. I simply 'pressed' the home button (⇧⌘H) in the simulator to stop the icons 'jiggling'.

The backboardd  process then went back to nearly 0% CPU.